# Is it possible to work on two data frames with Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have two data frames as below:

df1: revenue, year;
df2: year, orderID, orderAmount.

I would like to make an interactive plot via Shiny that plots revenue against year. For each year, there are many purchase orders. So I want to see all orders related to a year and their amounts when I click a datapoint on the revenue-year plot. Can this be possibly done via Shiny? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make a thing like powerBi Interactive plots in shiny?

Comment: Why not merge/combine the datasets, then plot the merged data?

Comment: As there are more than one purchase orders for each each, combing the datasets would lead to duplicated data of revenue and year in the new dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [plotly](https://plot.ly/r/shiny-coupled-events/)

From plotly help on shiny:
Plotly supports two separate click events that can be used to read user inputs using the `event_data()` function.

`plotly_selected` can be used to return information about data points inside a selection box (box or lasso)
`plotly_click` can be used to return information about a single data point